# Boxplot add thousands separator to y axis

Tags: r, plot

With base R (ie. no libraries):

```
boxplot(apartamentos$Preco ~ apartamentos$Tipologia, main = "Intervalo de preços por tipologia", options(scipen = 5))
```

Returns:

[image]

I want to add a thousands separator to the y-axis.

I know this should be simple and I've searched the documentation, but it's really complicated and I can't find it anywhere, so thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2):

```
set.seed(42)
d = abs(rnorm(1000)) * 10000
graphics.off()
boxplot(d, yaxt = "n")
axis(2, pretty(d), formatC(pretty(d), format = "f", big.mark = ",", digits = 0))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! That's really scary. It kind of removes the original y-axis and adds a new one with the thousands separator, but ends on 800.000 instead of 1.000.000.

Comment: @NunoNogueira, that's because of the `pretty`. You can instead give your own breaks manually at desired intervals. Read more at `?axis`